# Python sqlite3 parameterized drop table

Tags: python, sqlite, parameterized-query, sql-drop

I have a problem with dropping sqlite3 table in python. I am using standard `sqlite3` module.

```
self.conn = sqlite3.connect(...)

sql = """ drop table ? """
self.conn.execute( sql, (u'table_name',) )
```

gives me `OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

When I change `sql` to:

```
sql = """ drop table table_name """
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for table names nor column names.

Alternatively you could make it a two-step process, e.g.:

```
a_table_name = "table_a"
sql_stmt = f"""DROP TABLE {a_table_name}"""
self.conn.execute(sql_stmt)
```

And if you're doing that you may want to explicitly specify which tables can be deleted...

```
TABLES_THAT_CAN_BE_DROPPED = ('table_a','table_b',)
if a_table_name in TABLES_THAT_CAN_BE_DROPPED:
    # use code snippet from above 
else:
    pass # handle creatively
```

Comment: Too bad, I wanted to use `executemany()` with list of tables. Any idea if this would be somehow feasible?

Comment: Is looping over the table names too slow?

Comment: Of course not. I just love to make the things as simpliest as possible:). Thanks for the answer!