# How to drop a sqlite table in python according to a variable name passed through a function

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def refreshDatabase(table):
    
    c.execute("DROP TABLE ?", (table,))
        
    conn.commit()

    createNewTable(table)
```

Hey, how can I drop the Table that is declared as a parameter when calling the function? It doesn't seem to work with this syntax. thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the error message I get: 
    c.execute("DROP TABLE ?", (table,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607737/python-sqlite3-parameterized-drop-table)

You can't substitute table name at SQL side, so change it from Python (which is not safe of course)

```py
def refreshDatabase(table):
    c.execute(f"DROP TABLE {table}")
    conn.commit()
    createNewTable(table)
```

Comment: Please don't answer if the question has been answered elsewhere - just flag as a duplicate (as you did).